# Reputation resets to 1 after clicking on a proposal in Area 51

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I recently signed up for Area 51 and confirmed my email to gain 50 reputation, bringing it to a total of 51.

Then, I went to browse the Nutrition proposal and clicked on one of the questions. Now my reputation count is 1, and I can't upvote or comment on the question. When I return to the Area 51 homepage, my reputation is back to 51.

My badges do not change at all.

Is this a bug or do I have to gain reputation specific to that proposal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you click on one of the questions in the announcements box, you are being taken to [Area 51 Discuss](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com). This site acts like Area 51's Meta site and follows the same rules as other Meta sites on the network. Namely: **the reputation there is only updated once an hour** and is inherited from the main user (your Area 51 profile) when that update happens.

Your Area 51 profile: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/124549/dominatorx

Your Area 51 Discuss profile: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/124549/dominatorx

Comment: Inversely, the reputation you gain from metas is only added to your main profile once an hour?
Would the reputation limit apply to both the profiles or only individually to each?

Comment: @DominatorX You don't gain/lose reputation on Meta sites (or Area 51 Discuss). The only exception is here at Meta Stack Exchange, which is a standalone site.